# How to insert text to an existing Powerpoint Slide using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

I have tried three different approaches, to no avail.

First is:

```
$s = $presentation.Slides[$targetslide]


$tb = $s.Shapes.AddTextbox($horiz,$left,$top,$width,$height) 
$tb.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = $fla
```

the second is:

```
$f0a = ''
#$f1a is text to insert 
$presentation.Slides[$targetslide].Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange.Replace($f0a, $f1a)
```

and the third is:

```
$s = $presentation.Slides[$targetslide]



$s.Shape[1].TextFrame.TextRange.Text = $fla
```

Neither seem to work. Do you have any suggestions as to what I should try?

Comment: Approach 1 works fine for me, using `(1,0,0,20,20)` as the arguments to `AddTextBox`. Approach 2 works too, given correct arguments, passing a blank as the first argument (`$f0a`) won't replace anything. Approach 3 works if I use `Shapes[1]` instead of `Shape[1]`.

Comment: I tried that and with a few print statements, I found that for some reason it was correctly detecting the text I want to replace and what I want to pass into it, but the $s.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange.Text = $fla was just nuking the text in the text box. However, when I tried: $f0a=$s.Shapes[5].TextFrame.TextRange.Text
$test = $s.Shapes[5].TextFrame.TextRange.Replace($f0a, $f1a)

it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently,

```
$f0a=$s.Shapes[5].TextFrame.TextRange.Text

$test = $s.Shapes[5].TextFrame.TextRange.Replace($f0a, $f1a)
```

works perfectly.